# How to encode ȭ into readable string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, encoding, encode

I am fetching text data from URL and there is one specific character that doesn't seem to be encoded correctly -> ȭ

I know what that character is so I tried to manually encode that into utf-8, but xcode doesn't even recognize that character

```
NSLog(@"before: %@", brokenCharacter);
if([brokenCharacter isEqualToString: @"ȭ"]) brokenCharacter = @"A";
NSLog(@"after: %@", brokenCharacter);
```

I get NSLog as:

```
before: ȭ
after: ȭ
```

Will there be any solution to this problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The above code works fine for me if I add `NSString *brokenCharacter = @"ȭ";`. How are you actually setting this up? Are you sure the incoming string is actually ȭ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be use `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding` as encoding parameter

```
NSString *brokenCharacter = @"ȭ";
NSLog(@"before: %@", brokenCharacter);
NSData *dataCharacter = [brokenCharacter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
brokenCharacter = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[dataCharacter bytes]];
NSLog(@"after: %@", brokenCharacter);
```

Comment: I tried all options for dataUsingEncoding:, but nothing decoded that one character right.. it spit out something like /&#de?$... So I guess i have to look at the server-side. I dunno why that server is sending that one character broken while all the rest of data fine. But thanks for your answer.